# Does Ruby's XMLRPC::Client have call size limitations?

Tags: ruby, xml-rpc

I'm using `XMLRPC::Client` in Ruby (same behavior for ruby 1.8 to 2.0) for sending calls to a server, as follows:

```
server = XMLRPC::Client.new2( url )
server.timeout = 300
response = server.call( "service.methodname", bigarray )
```

Everything works fine, as long as the `bigarray` that is passed on is not too big. From the moment it contains about 10K floats, I get the following error trace:

```
$ ruby client_largeinputset.rb 
/Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:122:in `read_all'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:292:in `block in read_body_0'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:269:in `inflater'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:274:in `read_body_0'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:201:in `read_body'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:163:in `reading_body'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `block in transport_request'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1402:in `catch'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1402:in `transport_request'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1321:in `request_post'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/xmlrpc/client.rb:477:in `do_rpc'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/xmlrpc/client.rb:281:in `call2'
from /Users/aliekens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/xmlrpc/client.rb:262:in `call'
from client_largeinputset.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I am not aware of call size limitations in XMLRPC's specifications, but there seems to be a restriction somewhere in my workflow.

First off: Is this my ruby client's problem or is this a problem with my server (written with xmlrpc-c, over an Abyss HTTP server) which is possibly not accepting big requests?

If it is on the client side, then is there a way to circumvent this problem? Can I change the size of call requests on the client side (if there are limitations)? Are there any alternative routes (besides ruby's native XMLRPC::Client implementation) that may circumvent this problem? Preferably I am looking for a solution that solves this on the client side without having to tweak the server side, unless it is indeed a problem on the server size.

Comment: How large is the XML request that is being generated by your client?  Is this not perhaps too large for the server to process?

Comment: McFinnigan, I have no idea how big (in bytes) the XML request generated by Ruby's XMLRPC::Client is. But I understand from your question that you may also suspect that this is more likely the server's instead of the client's problem? I'll try to see whether I can write a small C client in order to investigate. Beyond XMLRPC, the server should be able to handle the call.